# Sharing attributes between classes: is multi-inheritance right and "pythonic" here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, multiple-inheritance

I have an use case where multi-inheritance seems the right way to go. But it implies sharing attributes between "sibling" classes, attributes that are initialized on other classes (so somehow unknown for them).
I'm asking if this below is a "right" and "pythonic" model, or should I better go with a dertivated-classes model.

Let's say we want to develop different deliverers, which will take some source data, apply some format to it, and send it through some channel. And this three parts (data - format - send) can be customizable for each case.

First, come code to make the examples below working:

```py
import sys
PY3 = not sys.version_info < (3,)
from string import Template
import csv, io, smtplib, requests, os

def read_test_movies(year_from, year_to, genre= None):
  TEST_MOVIES= [
    {'year': 1971, 'release': '01/01/1971', 'genre': 'thriller', 'title': 'Play Misty for Me'},
    {'year': 1973, 'release': '02/02/1973', 'genre': 'romantic', 'title': 'Breezy'},
    {'year': 1976, 'release': '03/03/1976', 'genre': 'western', 'title': 'The Outlaw'},
    {'year': 1986, 'release': '04/04/1986', 'genre': 'war', 'title': 'Heartbreak'},
    {'year': 1988, 'release': '05/05/1988', 'genre': 'music', 'title': 'Bird'},
    {'year': 1992, 'release': '06/06/1992', 'genre': 'western', 'title': 'Unforgiven'},
    {'year': 1995, 'release': '07/07/1995', 'genre': 'romantic', 'title': 'The Bridges of Madison County'},
    {'year': 2000, 'release': '08/08/2000', 'genre': 'space', 'title': 'Space Cowboys'},
    {'year': 2003, 'release': '09/09/2003', 'genre': 'trhiller', 'title': 'Mystic River'},
    {'year': 2004, 'release': '10/10/2004', 'genre': 'sports', 'title': 'Million Dollar Baby'},
    {'year': 2006, 'release': '11/11/2006', 'genre': 'war', 'title': 'Flags of Our Fathers'},
    {'year': 2006, 'release': '12/12/2006', 'genre': 'war', 'title': 'Letters from Iwo Jima'},
    {'year': 2008, 'release': '13/11/2008', 'genre': 'drama', 'title': 'Changeling'},
    {'year': 2008, 'release': '14/10/2008', 'genre': 'drama', 'title': 'Gran Torino'},
    {'year': 2009, 'release': '15/09/2009', 'genre': 'sports', 'title': 'Invictus'},
    {'year': 2010, 'release': '16/08/2010', 'genre': 'drama', 'title': 'Hereafter'},
    {'year': 2011, 'release': '17/07/2011', 'genre': 'drama', 'title': 'J. Edgar'},
    {'year': 2014, 'release': '18/06/2014', 'genre': 'war', 'title': 'American Sniper'},
    {'year': 2016, 'release': '19/05/2016', 'genre': 'drama', 'title': 'Sully'}
  ]
  out= []
  for m in TEST_MOVIES:
    if year_from <= m['year'] and m['year'] <= year_to:
      if genre is None or (genre is not None and genre == m['genre']):
        out.append(m)
  return out
```

Being this three parts (data - format - send) so distinguishable, we would start with these interface-like classes (I guess [abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) could be used too):

```py
class ITheData(object):

  def __init__(self, year_from, year_to, genre= None):
    self.year_from= year_from
    self.year_to  = year_to
    self.genre    = genre

  def readMovies(self):
    raise NotImplementedError('%s.readMovies() must be implemented' % self.__class__.__name__)

class ITheFormat(object):
  def filename(self):
    raise NotImplementedError('%s.filename() must be implemented' % self.__class__.__name__)

  def make(self):
    raise NotImplementedError('%s.make() must be implemented' % self.__class__.__name__)

class ITheSend(object):
  def send(self):
    raise NotImplementedError('%s.send() must be implemented' % self.__class__.__name__)
```

For each custom deliver, we will subclass the three of them, and put them together in a class like:

```py
class ITheDeliverer(ITheData, ITheFormat, ITheSend):
  def deliver(self):
    raise NotImplementedError('%s.deliver() must be implemented' % self.__class__.__name__)
```

So, we could have two different data sources. Apart from source, they may differ on post-processing actions. Although for simplicity I'm just doing a `self.readMovies()` all over the place, it could be some other custom method on the subclass.

```py
class TheIMDBData(ITheData):
  def readMovies(self):
    # movies = some_read_from_IMDB(self.genre, self.year_from, self.year_to)
    movies= read_test_movies(self.year_from, self.year_to, self.genre)
    return movies

class TheTMDbData(ITheData):
  def readMovies(self):
    # movies = some_read_from_TMDb(self.genre, self.year_from, self.year_to)
    movies= read_test_movies(self.year_from, self.year_to, self.genre)
    return movies
```

We could use also two different formats:

```py
class TheTXTFormat(ITheFormat):
  def filename(self):
    # Here `genre`, `year_from` and `year_to` are unknown
    params= {'genre': self.genre, 'year_from': self.year_from, 'year_to': self.year_to}
    return Template('movies_of_${genre}_from_${year_from}_to_${year_to}.txt').substitute(**params)

  def make(self):
    # Here `readMovies()` is unknown
    strio = PY3 and io.StringIO() or io.BytesIO()
    for movie in self.readMovies():
      line= Template('$title, released on $release').substitute(**movie)
      line+= '\n'
      strio.write(line)
    strio.seek(0)
    return strio.read()

class TheCSVFormat(ITheFormat):
  def filename(self):
    # Here `genre`, `year_from` and `year_to` are unknown
    params= {'genre': self.genre, 'year_from': self.year_from, 'year_to': self.year_to}
    return Template('movies_of_${genre}_from_${year_from}_to_${year_to}.csv').substitute(**params)

  def make(self):
    # Here `readMovies()` is unknown
    strio = PY3 and io.StringIO() or io.BytesIO()
    writer = csv.writer(strio, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    header = ('Title', 'Release')
    writer.writerow(header)
    for movie in self.readMovies():
      writer.writerow((movie['title'], movie['release']))
    strio.seek(0)
    return strio.read()
```

And two different sending channels:

```py
class TheMailSend(ITheSend):
  host      = 'localhost'
  sender    = 'movie@spammer.com'
  receivers = ['movie@spammed.com']

  def send(self):
    # Here `make()` is unknown
    print('TheMailSend.send() Sending to %s' % str(self.receivers))
    try:
      message = self.make()  # Format agnostic
      smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP(self.host)
      smtpObj.sendmail(self.sender, self.receivers, message)
      return True, 'ok'
    except Exception as ss:
      return False, str(ss)

class TheWSSend(ITheSend):
  url = 'spammed.com/movies/send'

  def send(self):
    # Here `make()` is unknown
    print('TheWSSend.send() Sending to %s' % str(self.url))
    try:
      content = self.make()  # Format agnostic
      s= requests.Session()
      response= s.post(url= self.url, data= {'content': content})
      s.close()
      if response.status_code == 200:
        return True, 'ok'
      else:
        return False, response.status_code
    except Exception as ss:
      return False, str(ss)
```

So, we could end with some deliverers like these:

```py
class TheIMDBToTXTFile(ITheDeliverer, TheIMDBData, TheTXTFormat):
  def __init__(self, year_from, year_to, genre= None):
    TheIMDBData.__init__(self, year_from, year_to, genre)

  def deliver(self):
    filepath= os.path.join('/tmp', self.filename())
    f= open(filepath, 'w')
    f.write(self.make())
    f.close()
    print('TheIMDBToTXTFile.deliver() => Successfully delivered to %s' % str(filepath))

class TheIMDBToWS(ITheDeliverer, TheIMDBData, TheTXTFormat, TheWSSend):
  def __init__(self, year_from, year_to, genre=None):
    TheIMDBData.__init__(self, year_from, year_to, genre)

  def deliver(self):
    ok, msg = self.send()
    if ok:
      print('TheIMDBToWS.deliver() => Successfully delivered!')
    else:
      print('TheIMDBToWS.deliver() => Error delivering: %s' % str(msg))

class TheTMDbToMail(ITheDeliverer, TheTMDbData, TheCSVFormat, TheMailSend):
  def __init__(self, year_from, year_to, genre=None):
    TheTMDbData.__init__(self, year_from, year_to, genre)

  def deliver(self):
    ok, msg= self.send()
    if ok:
      print('TheTMDbToMail.deliver() => Successfully delivered!')
    else:
      print('TheTMDbToMail.deliver() => Error delivering: %s' % str(msg))
```

And they work fine -with obvious connection errors-:

```
>>> imdbToTxt = TheIMDBToTXTFile(year_from= 2000, year_to= 2010)
>>> imdbToTxt.deliver()
TheIMDBToTXTFile.deliver() => Successfully delivered to /tmp/movies_of_None_from_200_to_2010.txt
>>> 
>>> imdbToWs = TheIMDBToWS(year_from= 2000, year_to= 2010)
>>> imdbToWs.deliver()
TheWSSend.send() Sending to http://spammed.com/movies/send?
TheIMDBToWS.deliver() => Error delivering: 405
>>> 
>>> tmdbToMail = TheTMDbToMail(year_from= 1980, year_to= 2019, genre= 'war')
>>> tmdbToMail.deliver()
TheMailSend.send() Sending to ['movie@spammed.com']
TheTMDbToMail.deliver() => Error delivering: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

But, as commented, some attributes are unknown for some classes, and the linter is -obviously- complaining about it:

```
Instance of 'TheTXTFormat' has no 'genre' member
Instance of 'TheTXTFormat' has no 'year_from' member
Instance of 'TheTXTFormat' has no 'year_to' member
Instance of 'TheTXTFormat' has no 'readMovies' member

Instance of 'TheCSVFormat' has no 'genre' member
Instance of 'TheCSVFormat' has no 'year_from' member
Instance of 'TheCSVFormat' has no 'year_to' member
Instance of 'TheCSVFormat' has no 'readMovies' member

Instance of 'TheMailSend' has no 'make' member
Instance of 'TheWSSend' has no 'make' member
```

So, the question remains: is here multi-inheritance a good model?

The alternatives could be: a derivated-classes model, or just independent classes and passing around parameters like `data` or `formatter`. But none of them seem so simple as multi-inheritance (although they'd fix linter -and probably conceptual- problems).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think inheritance is a good model here. You have lots of classes and it gets messy.

I think It's ok to implement inheritance for different "flavors" of the same step, of using the "Template pattern" described [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method/python/example).

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class ITheSend(ABC):

    def run(self) -> None:
        """
        The template method defines the skeleton of an algorithm.
        """

        self.pre_send_hook()
        self.send()
        self.post_send_hook()

    # These operations have to be implemented in subclasses.

    @abstractmethod
    def send(self) -> None:
        pass

    # These are "hooks." Subclasses may override them, but it's not mandatory
    # since the hooks already have default (but empty) implementation. Hooks
    # provide additional extension points in some crucial places of the
    # algorithm.

    def pre_send_hook(self) -> None:
        pass

    def post_send_hook(self) -> None:
        pass


class TheMailSend(ITheSend):
  host      = 'localhost'
  sender    = 'movie@spammer.com'
  receivers = ['movie@spammed.com']

  def send(self, message):
    print('TheMailSend.send() Sending to %s' % str(self.receivers))
    try:
      smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP(self.host)
      smtpObj.sendmail(self.sender, self.receivers, message)
      return True, 'ok'
    except Exception as ss:
      return False, str(ss)

class TheWSSend(ITheSend):
  url = 'spammed.com/movies/send'

  def send(self, content):
    print('TheWSSend.send() Sending to %s' % str(self.url))
    try:
      s= requests.Session()
      response= s.post(url= self.url, data= {'content': content})
      s.close()
      if response.status_code == 200:
        return True, 'ok'
      else:
        return False, response.status_code
    except Exception as ss:
      return False, str(ss)
```

However, for the full chain I'd explore composition instead of inheritance.

```py
class Chain:
    def __init__(self, data, format, send):
        self._data = data
        self._format = format
        self._send = send

    def deliver(self):
        data = self._data.execute()
        format = self._format.execute(data)
        send = self._send.execute(format)


the_IMDB_to_TXT_file = Chain(send=ITheDeliverer, data=TheIMDBData, format=TheTXTFormat)
```